# CouchDB View - Multiple Filter

Tags: dictionary, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a question to couchdb views / map-reduce.

Lets say, we have a database with hotel-documents like the following:

```
[{
        _id: "1",
        name: "Hotel A",
        type: "hotel",
        stars: 3,
        flags: ["family-friendly","green-hotel","sport"],
        hotelType: "premium",
        food: ["breakfast","lunch"]
    }, {
        _id: "2",
        name: "Hotel B",
        type: "hotel",
        stars: 5,
        flags: ["family-friendly","pet-friendly"],
        hotelType: "budget",
        food: ["breakfast","lunch","dinner"]
    }]
```

To find all hotels with 3 stars, the following view will fit:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.stars, doc.name]);
}
```

If I use startkey=[3], everything is fine.

But how is it possible to make a view with multiple filters?

For example - all hotels:

- with 3 stars and the flags "family-friendly" and "pet-friendly" and
  with hotelType "budget"?
- with hotelType "premium" and food "breakfast" or "lunch"?
- etc.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have now decided to use good old mysql. CouchDB was a nice experience for me, but there are tooo much problems if you need more then the data of one document :(

Answer (score 2):

You can emit a key with a group of values:

```
emit([[doc.stars,doc.hotelType], doc.name]);
```

The problem is that this only works if you can order your attributes by importance since they will always get reduced in the same order. Kxepal's solution of using different views is probably the best for your situation.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
I know that I can emit more than one time and that i can use array's as keys. 

 function(doc) {
  // by name
  emit([1, doc.name]);
  
  // by hotelType
  emit([2, doc.hotelType]);
  
  // by flags
  for(var i in doc.flags) {
   emit([3, doc.flags[i]]);
  }
  // by stars and ONE flag(s)
  for(var i in doc.flags) {
   emit([4, doc. doc.flags[i]]);
  }
 }

But how can i search for example "by stars and MORE then ONE flags"? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different views for that. Each view will handle his own domain with own keys. You may create one-view-for-all-data via multiple emit with different `key` value, but in perspective it will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB views are one-dimensional. And you are looking for multi-dimensional query:

- x = stars
- y = flags
- z = hotelType

Multi-dimensional queries are not supported unfortunately. For example if you need query geographical location by latitude and longitude, than you'll have to use GeoCouch.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But is there any solution for my problem? Don't use couchdb? Use a list funtion? etc...

Comment: You need to consider an SQL database for this task.

Comment: Either you need SQL so that you can compare two values independently of one another or you need to create a view for every combination of search query you want to make. CouchDB is like this by design so that it can be scalable.